# ¿Por que me ejecuta esto en todas las lineas?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer que cada X lineas me inserte un tr con un espaciador, mas o menos lo tengo, pero cada vez que llego a la linea para meter el espacio, lo mete en todas las lineas en vez de en la linea que hace el salto.

estoy usando este codigo en javascript y jquery para hacerlo:

```
<script>
var Infactura_Lineanum = Contarlineas('.Lineas_Infactura');

const Infactura_N_Lineas = 35; //defino cuando quiero que salte la pagina

if (Infactura_Lineanum >= Infactura_N_Lineas) {
++Infactura_Pagina;
var Infactura_Lineanum = 0;
$('tbody').after('<tr class="Espaciador" />hola</tr>');
$('#doc_Infactura').append('<page size="A4" id="Pagina'+Infactura_Pagina+'" class="insertarDoc">'
+'<div id="cabeceradoc">Factura</div>'
+'<div class="logo"><img src="../Scripts/Imagenes/Empresas/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'];?>/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Logo'];?>" alt="<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Nombre'];?>" /></div>'
+'<div class="marca_agua"><img src="../Scripts/Imagenes/Empresas/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Id'];?>/<?=$_SESSION['Empresa_MarcaAgua'];?>" /></div>'
+'<div class="Empresa"><?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Nombre'];?></div>'
+'<div class="Registromercantil"><?=$_SESSION['Empresa_Registro'];?></div>'
+'<div id="Infactura_Totales_'+Infactura_Pagina+'">&nbsp;</div>'
+'<div class="Npagina">Pagina '+Infactura_Pagina+'</div>'
+'</page>');
$('#Infactura_Totales_1').appendTo('#Infactura_Totales_'+Infactura_Pagina); 
}
console.log('Linea Jump '+Infactura_Lineanum);
</script>
```

La linea implicada que se suponen que meten el salto de es:

```
$('tbody').after('<tr class="Espaciador" />hola</tr>');
```

El diseño es imitando unos folios en a4 y lo que quiero es que cada vez que llegue a la linea 35 inserte otra pagina y meta un espaciador entre las paginas para que no ponga texto en el pie de la pagina anterior ni en la cabecera de la siguiente.

En la siguiente imagen se ve como ha metido texto en el espacio reservado. Las dos ultimas lineas deberían estar en la pagina 2 pero mas abajo.

[image: Pagina]

Las lineas de producto están agrupadas por un tbody ya que necesito que tengan 2 tr cada linea ( aunque lo podría cambiar por listas numeradas si es mas fácil ).

Por ultimo aunque creo que no es relevante el contador de lineas que uso es este:

```
function Contarlineas(selector) {
    var height = $(selector).height();
    var line_height = $(selector).css('line-height');
    line_height = parseFloat(line_height)
    var rows = height / line_height;
    return Math.round(rows);
}
```

El espacio entre folios siempre es el mismo, aunque pueden existir infinitos folios y obviamente el tamaño de los folios también siempre es el mismo.

Comment: ¿Esta pregunta fue resuelta?

Answer (score 2):

> Estoy tratando de hacer que cada X lineas me inserte un tr con un espaciador

¿Entonces por qué agregas el espaciador a la tabla en lugar de a las filas?

```
$('tbody').after('<tr class="Espaciador" />hola</tr>');
```

Además, estás cerrando el tag `tr` de forma incorrecta. Fíjate en el `/>Hola`. Por otro lado, la función `jQuery#after` agrega un elemento **al final del mismo**; es decir, antes del cierre de la etiqueta misma (después de los hijos).

Si tu intención es que te inserte un espaciador cada X líneas, entonces, lo que debes hacer es agregar el espaciador luego de la fila que esté en el límite de X.

```
$('tbody tr').each(function (i) {
  if (i !== 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
    $(this).after('<tr class="Espaciador"></tr>');
  }
});
```